# Mac Aliases do not work with android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I want to add an alias of a folder which contains some Java code files to android studio as Package , but Android Studio is not recognizing the Alias of folder and asking me to select the type of file instead of showing the code files in it. Is there a way around for that , I do not want to copy the source file to my project. I want them to be at one place where they are right now and able to be edited in my android studio project.

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a symlink or a hardlink.

Comment: Symlink would only allow me to change the main Src folder path, but I have activities in src/main/ ..... I cannot change that. Is there a way to add something like Linking search path for xcode?